# Form doesn't show after hiding

Tags: jquery

I have this single page application that instead of pages, loads sections one at a time. The basics of this app is that you input a query and then go a results page, and on top of the results in another form - same as the first form but instead of going to a new view (into a different section of the same page) the results just appear below it. Whenever a new view loads, the other is hidden. (ex: home view has search form. Search, submit, hides home view and then results view)

Some of these views would have this form, and some do not, so when they don't, I hide the form:

The views have data with html sent from a remote server. Some of these views do not have a  form above above the pages, some do.

When the view doesn't have a form, I hide the form with the following function:

```
removeContent = function(){
    $('#analyze-results-form').hide();
    $('#pick-content').html(''); 
}
```

Which is stuck inside of this:

```
    getSomethingPicks = function(phoneId){
        var pickHolder = $('#PickHolder'),
        pickContent = $('#pick-content');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: 'http://www.something.com/something.php', 
            data: "something"+phoneId+"&something",
            beforeSend: function(){
                removeContent();
            },
            complete: function(data){  
                pickContent.html(data.responseText);    
            }   
        });
    }
```

This is ran when going to the #somePage after a click event.

So let's say we go to home view>menu view>SsomethingPage view>home view>results view.

Now because I hid the content in somethingPage view, the form that is required in results view does not show up. This is the code I am using for the results view, along with my attempt at fixing it.

```
getPickerData = function() {
    var tickerForm = $('#analyze-form'),
        tickerResultsFormClone = $('#analyze-results-form').clone();
        pickHolder = $('#PickHolder'), // The view where the results and second form resides
        pickContent = $('#pick-content'), // Where the results is loaded
        tickerHomeInput = $('#home #ticker'); // Value of the first ticker
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: 'http://www.1dayreturn.com/getPicksdev.php', 
        data: "action=GetEverything&stock="+tickerHomeInput.val()+"&application=android",
        beforeSend: function(){
            if (pickContent.length == 0) {
                pickHolder.html('');
                tickerResultsFormClone.prependTo(pickHolder);
                $('<div id="pick-content"></div>').appendTo(pickHolder);
                pickContent = $('#pick-content');
                console.log(tickerResultsFormClone);
            }
        },
        complete: function(data){
            pickContent.html(data.responseText);
        }  
    });
    /*
        Results form
     */
    var tickerResultsInput = $('#PickHolder #ticker');
    $('#results-submit-ticker').on('touchstart click', function(e){
        $('#analyze-results-form').show();
        console.log('clicked?');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: 'http://www.1dayreturn.com/getPicksdev.php', 
            data: "action=GetEverything&stock="+tickerResultsInput.val()+"&application=android",
            beforeSend: function() {
                pickContent.slideUp('400').html('<h2 class="searchloading">Searching for stock data...</h2>');
            },
            complete: function(data){
                $('.searchloading').hide('300');
                pickContent
                    .html(data.responseText)
                    .slideDown('400');
            }  
        });
    });
}
```

Because sometimes the  pickHolder has to be emptied, because of some content, I'm replacing and re-inserting the form. This works. The issue here is the second form part.

HTML:

```
<div id="PickHolder" class="view container">
    <form id="analyze-results-form" action="" class="analyze-form">
        <div class="input-container">
            <input id="ticker" class="input-stock" type="text" placeholder="Add Ticker">
            <em class="subtext">(GOOG, AAPL, YHOO, etc)</em>
        </div><!-- /.input-container -->
        <button id="results-submit-ticker" class="action action-data btn no-view" data-ref="#PickHolder">Analyze</button>
    </form>
    <div id="pick-content"></div>
</div>
```

But the form fails to show, and I am not sure why. The queston is, how can I get my form to show?

Comment: i think you need to post the html you are using. also it looks like you are hiding the form in the complete function after you populate the data...

Comment: Html would definitely help, but a quick question: is your form contained inside of `#pick-content` if it is, calling `$('#pick-content').html('');` will remove the form since your are setting the HTML inside to empty or `''`

Comment: Also, unquote the numerical values that dictate the speed (in ms) for `.slideUp()` and `slideDown()`: it should be `.slideUp(400)` instead of `.slideUp('400')`, for example.

Comment: @gabereal Hi, html added as well as the full JS for the home view form and results form. I'm cloning the form after the html is wiped.

Comment: and @Culyx, html added.

Comment: @Culyx Would really appreciate it if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of your `getPickerData` you have a query for the form:

```
tickerForm = $('#analyze-form')
```

The form has an ID of `analyze-results-form` and a class of `analyze-form`. In your selector you used a `#`, which is an ID selector, but you've used the form's class instead of its ID.

When you use jQuery and call a method, such as `.show()`, on a collection, and you don't see your change take effect, the first troubleshooting step should be to log the collection to the console to see if it even contains the elements you thought it did. If it does not, then troubleshoot your selector.

**Edit**: wait...there's so much more as I look through your code...

You never even use the `tickerForm` variable from that first line of code I pointed out to you.

Also, The `beforeSend` you wrote in the first ajax call inside of `getPickerData` makes very little sense to me...I don't understand why you're seemingly attempting to rebuild the contents of `#PickHolder` just because `#pick-content` is empty. **Regardless of that**, you are cloning the form before that and then removing the original form and putting the clone into place. The clone, however, was probably created from the original form *while it was hidden*. As such, the newly cloned one will have a style of `display: none;`. You need to call `.show()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery('#selector') selects only one element. And you have two of them, after tickerResultsFormClone.prependTo(pickHolder);

Change your script to:

```
removeContent = function(){
    $('.analyze-form').hide();
    $('#pick-content').html(''); 
}
```

and

```
$('#results-submit-ticker').on('touchstart click', function(e){
   $('.analyze-form').show();
...
```

see more https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/